# Add a SpaCy Tokenizer Exception: Do not split '>>'

Tags: nlp, tokenize, spacy

I am trying to add an exception to recognize '>>' and '>> ' as an indicator to start a new sentence. For example,

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
doc = nlp(u'>> We should. >>No.')

for sent in doc.sents:
    print (sent)
```

It prints out:

```
>> We should.
>
>
No.
```

But, I'd like it to print out:

```
>> We should.
>> No.
```

Thank you for your time in advance!

Comment: This answer might be what you are looking for: stackoverflow.com/a/51776803/2198727. You just need to adapt the character sequence to the one you want to tokenise (i.e. use '>>' as your special case pattern).

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a [custom component](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines#section-custom-components). The code examples provide a custom sentence segmentation [example](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/examples/pipeline/custom_sentence_segmentation.py). From the documentation, the example does the following:

> Example of adding a pipeline component to prohibit sentence boundaries
>   before certain tokens.

The code (adapting the example to your needs):

```
import spacy


def prevent_sentence_boundaries(doc):
    for token in doc:
        if not can_be_sentence_start(token):
            token.is_sent_start = False
    return doc


def can_be_sentence_start(token):
    if token.i > 0 and token.nbor(-1).text == '>':
        return False
    return True

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
nlp.add_pipe(prevent_sentence_boundaries, before='parser')

raw_text = u'>> We should. >> No.'
doc = nlp(raw_text)
sentences = [sent.string.strip() for sent in doc.sents]
for sentence in sentences:
    print(sentence)
```

**Output**

```
>> We should.
>> No.
```